# When did idea of document file format or markup language first appear?

Tags: history

I'm not *necessarily* asking for the first well-formed definition of some markup language, nor the first implementation of parser for one such language.

What I'd like to know is when did people first think they could/should embed formatting (or other) information into pure text. Wikipedia gives one early example of such language, which is actually a complete system, both a language and its implementation: [TYPSET and RUNOFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPSET_and_RUNOFF)

But I'm guessing there are even earlier examples.

I'd be satisfied even if the first idea was in a SciFi novel predicting that people would (before wysiwyg editors) write things in one way, with formatting tags etc., and later read this content in a processed form.

A very early example might be [didascalies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didascaly) from Greek plays, which were parts of text not meant to be read, but were affecting the way these parts are to be pronounced.  However, I'm looking for something less domain-specific. Something that originated with the idea (more or less) of a standarized way to add information to text, whether this is color in which text should be printed, a position information, or something purely semantical like "this is important" (*without* making this additional information a part of the text itself, as would be in adding something like (!!!) near the important stuff).

I think this question belongs equally to this site and *History SE*. I'm aware of (perhaps unavoidable, and partly even intentional) vagueness in this question, and hope it's no more vague than it should be. I will appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Would you count [proofreader's marks](http://www.espressographics.com/text/proofreader.html) as markup? If so, we know of examples from around the [13th/14th Century](https://vhmml.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/fixing-matthew-corrections-in-a-13th14th-century-manuscript/).

Comment: I would prefer something that doesn't add new type of content (nontextual or textual but with different alphabet), but your example is certainly in the spirit of what I'm asking. Thank for your help!

Comment: Are you only interested in markup within "pure text" and not, say, machine-readable encodings of text? The  [Baudot Code](http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/telecom/codes/baudot.html) (circa 1870) contained control sequences that specified whether the letters to follow were upper case or lower case. [Morse code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosigns_for_Morse_code) has a set of prosigns that indicate new line and new paragraph.